# Normal Gerund or Past form of the Gerund?

Tags: gerunds

I am trying to brush up on my grammar knowledge and I usually contemplate this situation.

> Todd Boehly is accused of 'knowing nothing about football' after sacking Thomas Tuchel  ([source](https://twitter.com/goal/status/1568327535838265349))

Don't you think that it is supposed to be "after having sacked Thomas Tuchel" This event took place in the past and the gerund form needs to be adjusted as well? In which situations do we use "having V3" or "to have V3?"

Comment: I think the quote marks you used were unclear, I changed them to italics.  Were the quote marks in the original.

Comment: The example sentence is unclear.  It is hard to understand who "he" and "him" refer to.  Is there a source for this sentence?

Comment: I suspect you are quoteing https://twitter.com/goal/status/1568327535838265349

Comment: Please quote exactly.  Don't change names to pronouns. Don't create a "minimal working example"!  Always give the source, and if that source is on the internet add a link.

Comment: Exactly i was quoting the situation about Tuchel but i didn't want to include his name :D You are right though and thank you for the correction, well noted!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there ism no such thing as "the past form of the gerund". A gerund is a word derived from a verb but functioning as a noun. In

> Todd Boehly is accused of 'knowing nothing about football' after sacking Thomas Tuchel.

the word "sacking " is not used as qa noun, and so is **not** a gerund.  Rather it is a present participle, which is a verb form. In regular verbs, it has the same form as the gerund, and so the two are often confused. Ther is a past participle, in this case "sacked", but it is not any sort of gerund.

The example sentence could be rewritten to use "after having sacked" in place of "*after sacking*". The meaning is basically unchanged, the difference is onr of style an emphasis. Either form would be grammatically valid, and quite natural.